# Traverse down the DOM to select only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Drupal 7 to generate content types to a single page. I have some jQuery set to append a button on each summary text. I have the body text hidden. When clicking the appended button, I'm trying to select only the nearest .hidden class and expand it upon clicking on the continue button. Ideally hiding the summary text on click as well. I have tried .find() .closest() without any luck.

```js
var slideBodyText = $('.featured-summary').append('<button class="continue btn btn-success">Continue</button>');

slideBodyText;
$('.continue').on('click',function(){
  $('.hidden').find('div.hidden').toggleClass('.hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="field-content">
    <div class="featured-summary">
      <p>show text initially, then hide on click of button</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      <div>
        <p>hidden text until botton is pressed.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field-content">
    <div class="featured-summary">
      <p>show text initially, then hide on click of button/p>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      <div>
        <p>hidden text until botton is pressed.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field-content">
    <div class="featured-summary">
      <p>show text initially, then hide on click of button</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      <div>
        <p>hidden text until botton is pressed.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: `.continue` is a child of `.featured-summary`, which is a sibling of `.hidden`.  The click event will need to go up to the closest `.field-content` and then find the `.hidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selects the common parent, find hidden in there, then toggles the class. Also, when using `toggleClass`, `addClass`, or `removeClass` you don't add leading the `.`

```js
var slideBodyText = $('.featured-summary').append('<button class="continue btn btn-success">Continue</button>');

slideBodyText;
$('.continue').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('.field-content').find('div.hidden').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="field-content">
    <div class="featured-summary">
      <p>show text initially, then hide on click of button</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      <div>
        <p>hidden text until botton is pressed.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field-content">
    <div class="featured-summary">
      <p>show text initially, then hide on click of button/p>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      <div>
        <p>hidden text until botton is pressed.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field-content">
    <div class="featured-summary">
      <p>show text initially, then hide on click of button</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden">
      <div>
        <p>hidden text until botton is pressed.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually have to remove my hidden class on my site because there's interfering classes that's causing to not work. Thanks for this though helped me out.